# Excel VBA macro finds and deletes only some of the needed cells

Tags: excel, vba, find

I'd like to create a really simple VBA macro for Excel which looks within a range of 9 columns and variable number of rows and finds cells containing specific words, then deletes their contents.
And I have this code currently:

```
Sub FindAllAndDelete()
'
'   
    Dim SearchRange As Range

    Range("B58:J58").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Set SearchRange = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

    Do While Not IsEmpty(SearchRange)
      Set c1 = SearchRange.Find("Missing")
        c1.ClearContents
      Set c2 = SearchRange.Find("NR")
        c2.ClearContents
      Set c3 = SearchRange.Find("NO")
        c3.ClearContents
    Loop

End Sub
```

which seems to find and delete the contents of only some of those cells, not all of them.
Could you tell me why this happens and maybe give me a hint how to fix it?

Comment: am getting an error while running this code. May be if you fix that, you will get the correct output

Comment: Yes, thanks for the remark, I forgot to mention that error and I am not sure what's causing it. As I don't seem to have a With block variable and the Object variables seem to be set, otherwise how is the code functioning for some of the contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically find will give you only the first instance of the item that you are looking you. You will have to use findnext as given below

```
Set SearchRange = Range("B58:J158")
  Set c = SearchRange.Find("NO")
  If Not c Is Nothing Then
    Do
        c.ClearContents
        Set c = SearchRange.FindNext(c)
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
  End If
```